# Should I expect to just start hearing stuff when I connect to an EchoLink conference server?

Tags: echolink

I've installed EchoLink on my Windows machine and on my iPhone, and EchoHam on my Mac.

At the moment, I have the TCP 5200 outbound allowed from any device on my LAN and UDP 5198-5199 forwarding to my Mac and when I go to the EchoLink firewall verification page it says I pass the test and I see EchoHam getting getting to the `*PINGTEST*` node.  All good.

I then connected to `*ECHOTEST*` and I can hear the prompt being read and I can record my voice and hear it played back.  So also good.

However, I then connected to the `*WORLD*` conference server, which showed 5 connections including me.  I didn't hear anything.  I waited a while and threw my call out there and still heard nothing.

I then connected to `*DODROPIN*` which showed 17 connections (a mix of calls and other conferences).  I again heard nothing.  (Though I didn't say anything in case there was something going on I couldn't hear.)

I waited a bit and then went over to my iPhone (which is using the relay and not a direct connection so I didn't need to mess with the port forwarding), verified that I could hear the prompt and record and hear playback on `*ECHOTEST*` and then went back to `*DODROPIN*`.  Still heard nothing.

Do I perhaps still have some config messed up?  Or is it typical for conference servers to not be generating audio at times even if there are a number of things connected to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting good results and good audio back from echotest, then your setup is good.

It's not unusual for people to just hang around on conference servers (or repeaters) not saying anything.  Maybe they connected and walked away or went to sleep and will be back later.  Maybe they're listening at work, but it's inconvenient to respond because they are busy.

Some channels are just naturally quiet.  Some are very busy with lots of active people that are likely to respond.  Also, there are scheduled nets that can get very busy.

Just keep looking through the channels, or pick one and wait there to find when it is busy.  Or become one of those who connect and rarely say anything... but maybe *you* can be the one to respond when someone calls!

Comment: Sounds as if Echolink conferences are becoming empty spaces like repeaters.

Comment: I was told years ago that there were too many echolink conference servers, and correspondingly, too many conferences.   But there are a few that are busy -- so busy I don't like to listen to them as background.  :)